# Insert operations and ValidatesOnDataErrors: controls reported to be invalid as soon as they are displayed

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

In wpf controls, such as TextBox, you can set ValidatesOnDataErrors=true.
You can also want to change the default value for UpdateSourceTrigger.
For insert operations the textbox initial value is often empty, so its content is supposed to be not valid and it will be rendered with a red border (sure you can override this with styles and templates and obtain what you want). My desired behavior is to validate the content of a control only after the user has changed its content or when he tries to save the data.
It seems to me that the only way to achieve this is to set UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, which is not very friendly with pure MVVM.
I have already read the following article, but I'm looking for something simpler.

http://www.shujaat.net/2011/01/updatesourcetrigger-explicit-for-mvvm.html

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set DataErrorValidationRule like this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="PropertyName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```